# question about inserting a variable into a mongodb

Tags: mongodb, go

I need help. I am a self learner and I am trying to understand how to insert a variable that I read from a csv. I want to use that variable and insert it into the mongo db repeatedly again until it finishes reading the csv file. The code is like this. I would really appreciate the help. I am going crazy looking over all the info and on stack overflow. if i can get this right so i can build some confidence in coding with go. thank you

````
        reader, err := csvreader.Read()
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        } else if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(reader)
        type Event struct {
            event_id   string `json: "event_id"`
            date_added string `bson: time.time`
        }
        var event = Event{
            event_id:   {}string reader,
            date_added: time.Now().Format("2006-01-02 15:04"),
        }
        result, err := cli.InsertOne(ctx, event)

        fmt.Println(result)```
````

Comment: What's your real problem? reading a CSV file or inserting it into MongoDB.  and please provide a related error message.

Comment: my problem is that i cant enter the reader variable into mongodb or via the comment, this is the err, i get 
"./eventid.go:45:18: syntax error: unexpected string in composite literal; possibly missing comma or }
./eventid.go:46:25: syntax error: unexpected ) at end of statement
./eventid.go:52:1: syntax error: non-declaration statement outside function body:

Comment: CSV reader Read() method return an array of string. So, in your struct initialization, you must select which element will be used such as `event_id: reader[0],`
see https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/csv#Reader.Read

Comment: this is what i get now,
"[02005D36C7085A22]
<nil>
[19005D34C04828FA]
<nil>
[19005D34C04B28FD]
<nil>
[11111111]
<nil>
[17005D369343234F]
<nil>"
i am getting nill now

Comment: `nil` is the returned error, which means no error, which means you inserted the record.

Comment: i check the db there was nothing inserted

Comment: what i wanted to do was read the csv file and insert the data into mongo db. not sure what is the best method to do so